# QT upload (PUT) a file

Tags: c++, qt, curl

I am using QT to upload a file to a web server. The web server accepts files using the following request:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data' 
-H 'Authorization: Token <token>' 
-F 'file=@file_to_upload.txt' 
https://some.web.site/api/v2/files/contents/
```

I am using roughly this QT calls to try to accomplish the same:

```
QHttpMultiPart multiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
QHttpPart filePart;

file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)

filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data");
filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
multiPart.append(filePart);

QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
QNetworkRequest req(url);
req.setRawHeader("Authorization", ("Token <token>").data());

QNetworkReply * reply(mgr.put(req, &multiPart));
```

Right now this is what I get from the server:

```
File object is missing or invalid.
```

Can someone stop what the QT part is missing compared to the curl command? I would guess qt is missing some step that curl does behind the scenes. I would rather prefer a solution that does not involve me putting the whole request together manually.

Comment: this seems to be a POST, not a PUT (those are different methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make some code modifications:

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

//add next lines
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/zip")); //or whatever type of your file.
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\""));
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, file.size());

//and your other code
filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
multiPart.append(filePart);
```

And also take attention that with `curl` you make `POST` request but with `Qt` - `put`. So also replace last line with this:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = mgr.post(req, &multiPart);
```

Comment: I addeded the new parts but still no go. ideas?

Comment: changed to post still the same thing... I will try to post the full code tomorrow

Comment: Finally figured it out. Needed to add filename to header: QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.extension\"")