# How to store document in directory instead of database

Tags: mysql, blob, storage

I have a MySQL database that works with electrical measures. It also has a table `contracts` containing contracts' parameters, and a table `documents` that contains the blobs of documents corresponding to certain contract:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| contract_id | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(512)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document    | longblob            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Documents are added and retrieved by users from the program that connects to the database. 
Recently the database has become too big, and I want to reduce its size at the expence of documents. So I guess that a field `document` should be a text reference to the file. Where should this reference refer to? Should it be a shared folder? How could user`s program access this place? I ask because I want to know what's the best practice in this case. Thanks.

Comment: do you use any scripting/programming language for data entry? like c, perl, ruby, python, php etc?

Comment: @marmeladze Program for users is written on Qt4/C++.

Comment: well then. create a storage folder and write files to there. in good scenario, user's program will not directly access here. you'll take it, write to a temporary folder, then server handler will read from tmp and write to final destination. 

i am not good at qt but there are relevant answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067014/qt-upload-put-a-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735595/uploading-files-using-qt-qnetworkrequest

Answer (score 0):

Many programmers consider it a good practice to store documents (pdfs, images, docs, spreadheets, etc) as files rather than as BLOBs in a dbms.

You didn't describe your server environment, so it's hard to suggest a directory structure for your storage.  If you *now* use more than one machine using your application, or you *ever will* use more than one machine, you need to put those documents on a shared file system, so all your machines can read them from a common location.

For example, you might create a shared folder on some server, then mount it on every machine running your application at

```
  /mnt/electricowizard/docs
```

Under this you might store your docs like this:

```
 /mnt/electricowizard/docs/cust_0001/2015/001.pdf
 /mnt/electricowizard/docs/cust_0001/2015/002.tif
 /mnt/electricowizard/docs/cust_0001/2015/contract003.docx
 /mnt/electricowizard/docs/cust_0001/2016/asbuilt001.jpg
 /mnt/electricowizard/docs/cust_0001/2016/asbuilt002.jpg
```

See the hierarchy?  customer / year / document. This is generally a good structure in a multi user system because it lets you isolate stuff for particular users. It also prevents any given file system directory from needing to hold too many documents; things can get inefficient when you do that, especially on Windows.

In your database table, you might have a column called `docpath` or something. It would contain values like these.

```
 /cust_0001/2015/001.pdf
 /cust_0001/2015/002.tif
 /cust_0001/2015/contract003.docx
 /cust_0001/2016/asbuilt001.jpg
 /cust_0001/2016/asbuilt002.jpg
```

The location of the file system (`/mnt/electricowizard/docs/`) is a configuration characteristic of your program, and the location of the docs within the file system is a characteristic of each doc.

There are other ways to organize documents, of course.  Many people have dealt with this problem using what they thought of as "images" rather than "documents." That fact should help you search for more information.

A widely adopted example: WordPress's `uploads` folder: